# Let $g(x,y,z)= \sqrt{x \cos y} +z^{2}$ find the points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $g(x,y,z)= \sqrt{x \cos y} +z^{2}$

Find $g(4,0,2)$ and $ g(2,\frac{\pi}{3},-1 ) $

The first point is okay but the second i cant get through

Comment: Why can't you get the second while you could get the first? You just need to replace the variables with the corresponding values.

Answer (score 2):

$g(2, \frac{\pi}{3}, -1) = \sqrt{2 \cos\frac{\pi}{3}} +1$

$\cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow g(2, \frac{\pi}{3}, -1) = \sqrt{2\cdot \frac{1}{2}} + 1 = 1+1 = 2$

Comment: +1: Nice and quick.  I'm sorry that my tag change collided with your edit suggestion.  Please copy the code again and notify me to approve it.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, thanks, done